# Cannot import PyQt4.QtGui

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have a working Python 2.6 install and just installed the PyQt4 built for Python 2.6 (available at http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download). When I try to import PyQt4.QtGui I get the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I'm on Windows 2k8 64-bit, but my Python install is 32-bit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the the PyQt4 directory containing Qt's applications and DLLs to your `PATH` environment variable.  In PowerShell, provided you didn't change any of your install paths, that'd be

```
$env:path += ';C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin'
```

Comment: For Anaconda distribution put "C:\Anaconda\Library\bin" (modify to suit your Anaconda location) to the beginning of PATH env. variable.

Comment: What about if it does not work even though we set the path? Still says `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution on another forum that worked for me. I needed to copy QtGui4.dll and QtCore4.dll into the ...\Python2.7.1\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4 directory. Note, I left the original in the bin directory.

Comment: This solution worked for me with Anaconda / Python 3.5 and PyQt4 that was installed with `conda`.

Answer (score 6):

I had installed PyQt4 from a `.whl` file (from the [unofficial windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4)) and got the same error.

I did what the answers suggested: checked that I installed the correct version, put my PyQt4 directory in the `PATH` environment variable and had `QtCore4.dll` and `QtGui4.dll`, however none of these worked.

The answer was to try and open the `designer.exe` program: it also had an error, but this time specified which DLL file was missing (it said `msvcp140.dll is missing from your computer`)

I then downloaded it off [dll-files.com](http://dll-files.com) and put it in the PyQt4 folder (`C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4`) and it worked.

I hope this helps !

Comment: Dear god... nothing else but this worked. I went through exactly 13 other solutions/suggestions before your one that worked. Just goes to show how valuable additional answers can be.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you installed Python x64 ? By default, the Python website makes you download the x32 version, you need to go to this page to download the x64 version and then it will work. I had the same issue and it was fixed this way.
https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Hope that will help someone.
Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

If this does not works, try search for QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll, etc. in your paths set in PATH environment variable. In my case I found some qt dll in c:\windows\system32, caused the same error message. I've deleted the dll files, and problem solved. 'C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin' was in my path, but that was not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the these solutions worked for me. I had Python 3.1 x64 with PyQt 4.8.2-1 x64 on my Windows 7 x64, but uninstalling them and installing the x86 versions of Python 3.1 and PyQt solved the problem for me.

Comment: OK, thanks for sharing this! Hope it will work for me, as all suggestions above didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Download the program from http://www.dependencywalker.com to see if there was missing dll.

You need to point the program to the QtGui.pyd file from PyQt.

My case was using MSYS2's mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-pyqt4, it needed libpython3.5m.dll while pacman was already at python3.6

Answer (score 0):

I usage Linux ubuntu 14.04,firstly, Cannot import PyQt4.QtGui because access module PyQt4 not Available in group permission..
if call interpreter:`shell>> python` not available module QtGui, but if i call interpreter `sudo python` available QtGui.So, I solved this error , `Change permisions folder package PyQt4 in my virtualenv,from property folder,change Owner and Group`.

Its works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me with 64bit Python 3.5.  I ended up rolling back Anaconda to 4.1.1 (4.2.0 uses a Qt5 by default, which may or may not be the problem).  I also had to install pyqt from a python 3.5 whl - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4.

The binary file on the Riverbank website did not work for me, possibly it only works on Python 3.4?

I have installed pyqt with Anaconda several times, and I believe if it is done correctly the PATH does not need modification (it happens as part of installation) and DLLs do not need to be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that PyQt4 is for 32 or 64 bits?, I had the same problem I was using python 2.7.13  32 bit in Windows 10 and PyQt4 4.11 64 Bit, and changed PyQt4 for a 32 bit and it work immediately.