# While importing PyQt4.QtGui gets ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, pyqt4, importerror

While importing PyQt4.QtGui module in Python2.6 interpreter I get

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import PyQt4.QtGui
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

I've PyQt-Py2.6-gpl-4.6 lib file installed in my site-packages folder.
I tried to google it, but didnt find the fix for it, please help in this regards !

---

error fixed with the solution here :

[Cannot import PyQt4.QtGui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738879/cannot-import-pyqt4-qtgui)

Add the the PyQt4 directory containing Qt's applications and DLLs to your `PATH` environment variable. In PowerShell, provided you didn't change any of your install paths, that'd be

```
$env:path += 'C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\bin'
```

thanks anyway !

Comment: You should probably post your solution as the answer and accept it so this doesn't show up in the unanswered questions list.