# pyuic4 import QtCore DLL failed error

Tags: python, user-interface, dll, pyuic

I am trying to convert a ui file to a py file using pyuic4. I keep getting errors. I have tried several answers including writing the command diffrently and checking to make sure I am running PyQt and Python both x64. Also I am in the directory where the input (ui) file is located. My code is

C:\Users\Charles\Desktop>pyuic4 -o printHam_widget.py testUi.ui
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C\Python34\Lib\sites-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic", line 31, in 
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I have also tried

C:\Users\Charles\Desktop>pyuic4 -x testUi.ui -o printHam_widget.py

I received that same error.

Comment: This suggests that the program cannot load the QtCore DLL. I would [try the answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738879/cannot-import-pyqt4-qtgui)

Comment: None of those helped me, anyother ideas?

Comment: Re-install PyQt4? This often happens because of a problem with the install.

Comment: @cdbean04. Are you sure that the necessary PyQt directories are on your `PATH`? What is the output of `echo %PATH%`?